# Can Haskell's Opaleye DSL generate any given SQL?

Tags: haskell, opaleye

My team uses `Opaleye` to query `Postgres` from `Haskell`.

However, we also use raw `SQL` to do such things as:

- Initialize the database. Including commands `create database` and `create table`
- Perform database migrations when we change our schema, including varied commands.

**Is it possible to entirely replace this raw `SQL` code with `Opaleye`?**

Can `Opaleye` replace any `SQL`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the Opaleye tutorial](https://github.com/tomjaguarpaw/haskell-opaleye/blob/35de12d5736bf785ae7fc687055ea4450fd9ded7/Doc/Tutorial/TutorialBasic.lhs#L41-L43), creating tables and databases is currently unsupported:

> Opaleye assumes that a Postgres database already exists.  Currently
>   there is no support for creating databases or tables, though these
>   features may be added later according to demand.